# It the any map app which is using google maps APIs but work perfectly without GPS?

Tags: applications, gps, google-maps, maps, navigation

As I have searched - everybody asking about OFFLINE maps, but I am asking about maps which can use just simple google maps, but does not ask any permissions to GPS.

Currently original goolge maps are without GPS location permission, but they are not working until I turn ON the GPS. Maybe there is any option to force google maps working without asking any location data.

Usually, I know my exact location (when I am walking) or I can determine it very fast - just go to the road cross and you know your position +/- 50 meters. Then I just want to find the shortest way to location I choose.
I don't need any offline map - it won't save battery. But turning the GPS off - does.

*Edited:*
Turn on the battery saving is not an option - the vibration will be turned off. I don't use sound for calls (I even don't know what is the current ringtone). But you gave the nice idea - just turn ON the GPS, launch maps (without any permission) and after that turn off GPS.

Comment: On my android 6 (DTEK50) is does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to save battery life by disabling GPS, then simply disable GPS. In Settings, set location mode to "Battery saving" (WiFi + Bluetooth, but no GPS). This leaves location services on, but disables GPS. Android will still locate your device using WiFi techniques, but not using orbiting satellites, which takes more power.

[image]

Further, I can use Google Maps without location services enabled, at least on Android 8.1. Google Maps asks you to enable location services, but you can just say no.

Comment: I have android 6. something.  Actually, I don't need any location services - just direct access to the google maps - but now I have found the solution - just turn on the GPS, open maps, turn off the GPS.

Comment: @XuMuK The screenshot for the location mode is shown. This does not affect vibration. "Battery Saving" under the Battery setting menu may disable vibration, but this is a separate setting.

Comment: Yes, I understand, it SHOULD not affect, but id does. With battery saving mode ON all vibrations are OFF. Maybe it is my phone/android feature.